# Eclipse platform java how to display data from db into jtable

Tags: java, mysql

How can I display data from the database into the  JTable ?
I managed to display the data in the console but IN JTABLE  it does not display even the Jtable does not appear on the Jframe  yet Isee no error . please any help will be appreciated .

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class ju {
    private static Object request;
    static JTable mysTable;
    //constructor method

    public static void main (String args []){

        mysTable = new JTable(3,2);
        JScrollPane myPanel = new JScrollPane(mysTable,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                              JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        mysTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,70));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("King Musa Saloon Software");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(mysTable);
        //frame.add(mysTable);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver loading success!");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saloon";
            String name = "root";
            String password = "";

            try {
                java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
                System.out.println("Connected.");
                // pull data from the database 
                java.sql.Statement stmts = null;
                String query = "select  userid, username, name from saloonuser ";
                stmts = con.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = stmts.executeQuery(query);
                int li_row = 0;
                while(rs.next()){
                    mysTable.setValueAt(rs.getString("username"),li_row,0);
                    mysTable.setValueAt(rs.getString("name"),li_row,0);
                    int userid = rs.getInt("userid");
                    String username = rs.getString("username");
                    String name1     = rs.getString("name");
                    System.out.println(name1);
                    li_row++;
                }  
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so done.  Have a look at this:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DisplayResultSetinTableJTable.htm

The code you posted is awful.    I'd recommend throwing it away and starting from scratch.

Break up the problem.  Forget the UI for now.  Write a DAO that does nothing but access the database and bring back the data you need.  Test it and put it aside.  Then start on the UI.  Give it an instance of the DAO class and only worry about displaying the data it brings back.

Comment: I have tried that but no success

Comment: What did you try?  You cut & pasted the code from that link?  If yes, what happened?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem but now the Jscroll is the probklem